Error:Configuration file not found in directory “/” for command serverless config
I am deploying an Express.js application using the Serverless framework on AWS, but the command below is giving an error
Command :

$serverless config credentilas --provider aws --key XXXXXX --secret
XXXXXXX

Operating system: Windows 11
I tried to run the above command through the power shell with administrator privilege.


Typo: credentilas

I changed it to "credentials" but it did not work.

Have you tried --verbose or --debug logging? Do you have an aws config/credentials file in your D: directory?

yes, I am tired.

I got the same error message when I tried to use Serverless ϟ Framework 4.3.2. When I downgrade to version 3.39.0 it worked fine.
npm i serverless@3.39.0 -g

As part of the License changes, Serverless Framework Version 4 may contains breaking changes and disruptions for existing Services using the aws provider.
Read more at https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/upgrading-v4

The best alternative would be to do the following:
type serverless in your terminal and press enter. It will guide you through the process. choose your runtime /framework and continue. give it a name or choose one you created on Serverless Dashboard. Then it will ask about your credentials whether to save on local profile. I use local profile. then paste your credentials and all done. Hope it makes sense.
